# Translate3d not working properly in fullpage.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, fullpage.js

I'm building a site using fullpage.js and wordpress, everything works pretty nicely but everytime I try to disable the plugin in some way like using destroy() or just switching the setAutoScrolling to false the translate3d property is not resetting as it should. Also when I try to switch back the autoscroll to true is not working.

The "Visualizza" buttons on each slide will set the autoscrolling to false while the "rebuild" one on the last slide will reset it to true.

I quickly put a demo site to demonstrate my issue http://demopieve.direzionenuvola.it/ (access are: demo , demo). Looking online I didn't found anyone else having this issue and I didn't manage to find what is causing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are not using the latest version of fullPage.js (2.9.2 at the moment) that solves the issue as can be seen in the [releases changelog](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/releases) as well as in [the issue treating the topic](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/2426) in the issues tracker.

> Fixed bug: setAutoScrolling was broken #2426

Comment: thank you, I followed the guide on the github page and linked the files from the cdn so I thought they were already updated to the latest version